# Is it possible to have multiple <Directory>'s in a vhost.conf?

Tags: hosting, virtualhost

My webserver is running Plesk and for each new site a vhost.conf file is created that has some include_path and open_basedir settings in it:

```
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/global.website.nl/httpdocs/global:/tmp:/var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs"
php_value include_path "/usr/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/global.website.nl/httpdocs/global"
</Directory>
```

Is it possible to add another  for this site and have the include_path and open_basedir setting change for a subdirectory like this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs/subdirectory>
php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/global.website.nl/httpdocs/global2:/tmp:/var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs/subdirectory"
php_value include_path "/usr/share/pear:/var/www/vhosts/global.website.nl/httpdocs/global2"
</Directory>
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant `.../domain.com/conf/vhost.conf` file - these files are solely for customization, so you can include there whatever other settings you like.

But I guess you mean the autogenerated config of Plesk. If so, there would be 2 paths to add the lines you want

1. if you are on Plesk 11.0 and `/var/www/vhosts/website.nl/httpdocs/subdirectory` has a site assigned, then you can tune `open_basedir` and `include_path` in PHP settings of the site
2. if there are no site assigned, but you are on Plesk 10+, you can modify PHP templates used for the config generation. Read more about [Changing Virtual Hosts Settings Using Configuration Templates](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/68693.htm)

Comment: Thanks, it worked out changing the domain's vhost.conf. But thanks for the tip and link!